# Web page aligning badly on Internet Explore

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-9, internet-explorer-11

i have an app that will only be viewed on internet explorer,the page contents are positioned well in other browser on the center but in IE everything aligns to the left.I kindly need help

here is my css

```
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>SCOPE ACADEMY | HOME</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />

      <style>
      /* NOTE: The styles were added inline because Prefixfree needs access to styles and they must be inlined if they are on local disk! */
      @import url("http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,600,700");
@import url("http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.css");
*, *:before, *:after {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html, body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  font: 14px/1 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  color: #555;
  background: #fff;
}

h1 {
  padding: 50px 0;
  font-weight: 400;
  text-align: center;
}

p {
  margin: 0 0 20px;
  line-height: 1.5;
}

main {
  min-width: 320px;
  max-width: 800px;
  padding: 50px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: #fff;
}

section {
  display: none;
  padding: 20px 0 0;
  border-top: 1px solid #ddd;
}

input {
  display: none;
}

label {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 0 -1px;
  padding: 15px 25px;
  font-weight: 600;
  text-align: center;
  color: #bbb;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
}

label:before {
  font-family: fontawesome;
  font-weight: normal;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

label[for*='1']:before {
  content: '\f015';
}

label[for*='2']:before {
  content: '\f07c';
}

label[for*='3']:before {
  content: '\f0d6';
}

label[for*='4']:before {
  content: '\f085';
}

label[for*='5']:before {
  content: '\f109';
}

label:hover {
  color: #0066cc;
  cursor: pointer;
}

input:checked + label {
  color: #0066cc;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-top: 2px solid orange;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
}

#tab1:checked ~ #content1,
#tab2:checked ~ #content2,
#tab3:checked ~ #content3,
#tab4:checked ~ #content4,
#tab5:checked ~ #content5 {
  display: block;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 650px) {
  label {
    font-size: 0;
  }

  label:before {
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 18px;
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 400px) {
  label {
    padding: 15px;
  }
}
/*img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; bottom:1200; left: 0; right:0;
    margin: auto;
}*/

span.centerImage {
     text-align: center;
}

/*.footer {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    padding: 1rem;
    background-color: #efefef;
    text-align: center;

}
*/
/* IE 6 */
* html .footer {
   position:absolute;
   top:expression((0-(footer.offsetHeight)+(document.documentElement.clientHeight ? document.documentElement.clientHeight : document.body.clientHeight)+(ignoreMe = document.documentElement.scrollTop ? document.documentElement.scrollTop : document.body.scrollTop))+'px');
}

/*inline accordion css styles*/



    </style>

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prefixfree/1.0.7/prefixfree.min.js"></script>

</head>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Check if you closed all your tags..Like <div> ,but forgot</div>

Comment: post the content too

Comment: @EdwardOkech wer??

Comment: @affaz here is the content https://codeshare.io/2BAYzd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add display:block property for main tag

```
main {
 min-width: 320px;
 max-width: 800px;
 padding: 50px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 background: #fff;
 display:block; 
}
```